# Crash when assigning class variable

Tags: java, android, oncreate

In the *onCreate* section of my app, if I were to assign the extras string value to a string, it works. But when I try to assign it to a string element inside a custom structure it crashes with an *invoke static* error. Here's the code:

```
private AppData appData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
  String name = null;
  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      //String x = extras.getString("companyData");  //this works...
      appData.dbData = extras.getString("companyData");  //this crashes!  
      ...
      ...
```

And here's the *appData* class:

```
private class AppData {
  private String dbData;
  ...
  ...
}
```

Why isn't it allowing the assignment?

Comment: I'm sure that `appData` is null. Show us where it is coming from ?

Comment: Hi Suresh. It's declared just before the onCreate() method. I've added it.

Comment: Declared, but not initialized.

Comment: You're both absolutely correct! Absolutely missed the init. Thank you!

Comment: Just for completeness, `AppData` is an instance variable, not a class variable.

Comment: Instance variable; got it. Thanks Mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
private AppData appData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  appData = new AppData();   // create new instance 
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
  String name = null;
  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      //String x = extras.getString("companyData");  //this works...
      appData.dbData = extras.getString("companyData");  //this crashes!  
      ...
      ...
```

and:

```
private class AppData {
  private String dbData;
  // define a setter or 
  // define static vairble
  // private static String dbData = new String();
  public setDbData(String data)
   {
    dbData = data;  
        }

  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, M2E67. Is there any reason or advantage to using setters/getters over just accessing the variable directly? Isn't [appData.dbData = value] the same as [appData.setDbData(value)]?

Comment: it's related to encapsulation in programming language, you can search this and study more about implementing  programming languages and found several references

Comment: Protecting the instance variables. Thanks again.